# Accessing AD (active directory) Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, active-directory

I access the AD properties thru the below method. It works fine in my Local VHD (where I'm the domain/local/enterprise Admin) - but the same doesn't work when I access from a Domain user(who has only local admin access).

But the same Domain user(only with local admin access) access all the AD property details using the ADExplorer(SysInternal) tools.

Is it because that is unmanaged code and have Windows APIs to access and in .Net I need domain admin or some privilege ?

Or is there another way - which I'm missing in .Net to access the AD Properties without having an extra domain-level-privilege ??

```
public void getCurrentUserADDetails(string UserName)
{
   string ladpQueryStr = "LDAP://sp.com";

   DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ladpQueryStr);
   DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);

   srch.Filter = "(cn=" + UserName.ToLowerInvariant().Trim() + ")";

   srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
   srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
   srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("prop123");

   SearchResult searcResult = srch.FindOne();

   if (searcResult != null)
   {
      ResultPropertyCollection propertiesCollection = searcResult.Properties;

      List<DisplayClass> grdDataList = new List<DisplayClass>();

      foreach (string strKey in propertiesCollection.PropertyNames)
      {
         DisplayClass dispC = new DisplayClass();
         dispC.pName = strKey;
         dispC.pValue = Convert.ToString(propertiesCollection[strKey][0]);

         grdDataList.Add(dispC);
      }

      dataGridView1.DataSource = grdDataList;
   }
}
```

This is going to run in ASP.Net

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please post the exception you get with a domain user(non-admin)?

Comment: Does the user that owns the AppPool have access to AD?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using integrated authentification - in order for this to work you have to setup account delegation, unless you're running your application on a domain controller. This is a pretty tricky process, but there are a ton of info in Google.

Answer (score 0):

By using Explicit authentication and changing the Search filter, i got the results.

DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password, AuthenticationType);